# Why is this value not dropped after last use?

Tags: rust, mutex, deadlock

The following code deadlocks because the mutex is not unlocked after the last use of `v`:

```
use std::sync::{Arc,Mutex};

fn main() {
    let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(3));
    let mut v = a.lock().unwrap();
    *v += 1;
    println!("v is {v}");
    // drop(v);
    let b = Arc::clone(&a);
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut w = b.lock().unwrap();
        *w += 1;
        println!("w is {w}");
    }).join().unwrap();
}
```

The fix is to uncomment the explicit `drop(v)`. Why does compiler not automatically drop `v` after its last use?

In contrast, the Rust compiler knows to correctly drop `v` early in the following case:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 3;
    let v = &mut a;
    *v += 1;
    println!("v is {v}");
    let w = &mut a;
    *w += 1;
    println!("w is {w}");
}
```

This behavior seems natural, I would expect the compiler to do the same above.

Comment: because you are specifically in the main's scope so `v` will be dropped at the `}` of main.  If you explicitly want to drop v, your approach of `drop(v)` is correct. or you could `{  }` the references to `v`

Comment: Thank you for the response, but then why is v dropped automatically in the second code snippet before the scope of main ends? I did not create any block scope in that one either.

Comment: See the rules of how drop works here .... https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html

Comment: Technically v & w in the second example also shouldn't co-exist (two mutable references to the same thing). If you interchange line 4 & 5 it fails too. This also applies to complex containers. The answer by kmdreko clarifies this: The second case works because borrow checker is smart with references, while explicit drops occur at the end of scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Values are dropped when their scope ends, not after their last use. What may be confusing you is that the *borrow checker* knows *references* are inconsequential after their last use, and thus considers their lifetimes differently for the purposes of enforcing Rust's referential guarantees.

Technically `v` in the second example is not dropped until the end of the scope either, but there is no drop logic for references. See [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](/q/50251487/2189130)

Comment: This was on point, thank you so much!

Comment: Is it possible to fully explain this with NLL only? Don't you also need knowledge about how `MutexGuard` implementing `Drop` changes things? (I can't find a good article right now, besides the [rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dropck.html).)

Comment: @Caesar I wasn't trying to explain it all with NLL, only that the borrow checker doesn't quite use the same rules as when values are dropped. Certainly knowing how RAII wrappers use `Drop` to run automatic cleanup logic helps, but I'm not sure why the answer should be specific to `MutexGuard`.